# How to match only alpha versions, like 1.0.0-alpha.*

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, semantic-versioning

Using semver and NPM, is it possible to match only `-alpha` versions of a package?

`1.0.0-alpha.x` [doesn't work](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/1.0.0-alpha.x/1.0.0-alpha.123) because `x` is interpreted as a letter. `*` doesn't work either, it shows as [invalid](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/1.0.0-alpha.*/1.0.0-alpha.123).

`~1.0.0-alpha` doesn't work because if a `1.0.0-beta.0` version exists, for example, it will match that over all alpha versions. See [11.4](https://semver.org/#spec-item-11).

Answer (score 1):

Prereleases can be compared alphabetically, so `>=1.0.0-alpha <1.0.0-alpha0` should match only -alpha.* versions of 1.0.0.

Though, if beta versions are already released, why not just hard-code the latest existing alpha version?